# Python Selenium - Run javascript that's called on click event to return URL

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I have created a script to retrieve text from bet365 using selenium. The goal is to graph the changes through time. I have finished most of the script, but I'm working around the below problem by hand at the moment which is not ideal.

I have a list of elements that I want to get the URL from. the URL's are not in any href tags and they appear to me to be generated by javascript (when each element is clicked).

Because each page is quite heavy and takes time to load I don't want to click on each element, get the URL, then return back to the main page. I would prefer to call the javascript function and hopefully receive the URL back, is this possible?

Unfortunately i have no background in javascript and setting break points or inspecting the timeline is getting pretty overwhelming. So far i have found this  function in the chrome debugger which i think is what is creating the URL:

```
function hrefEvent(n){
    n =n || window.event;
    var t = n.target || n.srcElement, i = $(t), r;
    return t.href
}
```

Does this look like the piece of javascript i should be calling?

Can i call this script with selenium?

Answer (score 0):

selenium provides [execute_script](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.execute_script) method

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get("http://bet365/bet365")
driver.execute_script("function hrefEvent(n){n=n||window.event;var t=n.target||n.srcElement,i=$(t),r;return t.href?")
```

Comment: Thanks. yes i know about the execute_script method but im getting swamped with finding the javascript that i need to run.
i have tried copying what i think it the complete method, http://pastebin.com/quNdbEK1  , but i just returns None for each function call.